# Wordpress multisite non-www URL redirects to mainsite. www version of url is okay and comes to subsite homepage. Why?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress, no-www, www

So I just made a subsite today and everything was okay until I noticed:

If I type the URL of the subsite without the www part, it redirects to the main site.

Does anyone know why is that?

Before I made the subsite some months ago I did set up somewhere in some plugin or some file (I don't remember) www as my main domain and all the non www URLs were redirected to www version on the mainsite.

Now I created the subsite and this is what happens. I type in `example.com/subsite` and it sends me to `www.example.com`.

If I type `www.example.com/subsite`, then it sends me to `www.example.com/subsite...`

Anyone has an idea why this is?

I also have a Really Simple SSL activated on both sites individually, not network active. I tried changing it to network active but no help..

Answer (score 1):

Alright so it is a wordpress issue...
I am using wordpress v5.2.1.
just do the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} examplesite2.com [NC]
RewriteRule .*$ http://www.examplesite2.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

to top of `.htaccess`.

I am puzzled how this come dumb WordPress did not make this on its own. It is a multisite version of WordPress after all. Why is there this need for a damn user to go in and do this??? I am seriously puzzled. It is also sad how no one helps out. I asked in 3 forums.

Comment: The rule you've posted is not correct... it strips the URL-path and would result in a redirect-loop?! (Maybe something got lost in the copy/paste exemplification?) I would have thought the [WordPress stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) would be better suited to resolve this issue in a WordPress-related way? Oh wait, [you have asked there](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/388725/wordpress-multisite-non-www-url-redirects-to-mainsite-www-version-of-url-is-oka) and they've come up blank. Maybe the issue is with a plugin?